# Eigen compilation error with MPI

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, mpi, eigen

I am trying to do domain decomposition using Zoltan library and want to implement Eigen.
Unfortunately, the moment I include Eigen in the header `#include <Eigen/Dense>`, I get the following compilation error:

SRC/init_system.cpp:24:23: fatal error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory
 #include 
                       ^
compilation terminated.

Even, I have included the Eigen path in the makefile, as shown below:

```
CXX=mpic++

ID_TYPE_FLAG=-DZOLTAN_ID_TYPE_LONG_LONG

BLD=/home/kumar/Software/Zoltan/Zoltan_v3.83/BuildDir/src

SRC=/home/kumar/Software/Zoltan/Zoltan_v3.83/src

ZOLTAN_INCLUDE=-I$(SRC)/include

ZOLTAN_CONFIG_INCLUDE=-I$(BLD)/include

ZOLTAN_UTIL_INCLUDE=-I$(SRC)/zz  \
                    -I$(SRC)/par \
                    -I$(SRC)/order \
                    -I$(SRC)/tpls \
                    -I$(SRC)/lb \
                    -I$(SRC)/params \
                    -I$(SRC)/Utilities/shared


CXXFLAGS  = -Wall -g3 -std=c++11 -I include/eigen3 -$(ID_TYPE_FLAG)

COPT    = -DMKL_ILP64 -m64

LIBS    = -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -lzoltan -lparmetis -lmetis -lptscotch -lscotch -lptscotcherr -lscotcherr

CXXFLAGS =$(ID_TYPE_FLAG)

ODIR    = /OBJ
CFILES  := $(wildcard SRC/*.cpp)
OFILES  := $(addprefix OBJ/,$(notdir $(CFILES:.cpp=.o)))

meshl:  $(OFILES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(OFILES) $(LIBS)
OBJ/%.o: SRC/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(COPT) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f OBJ/*.o
```

The domain decompositoin code using Zoltan is compiling absolutely fine with mpi when the header for Eigen is NOT included in the code.

Any help in this regard for implementing Eigen would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time !!

Comment: You should provide an absolute path to the headers.

Comment: Hello Zulan, I tried the same by adding absolute path of eigen in the makefile: CXXFLAGS  = -Wall -g3 -std=c++11 -$(ID_TYPE_FLAG) -I/home/kumar/Dokumente/trial/include/eigen3. But the problem still remain the same.

Comment: Is there a file `/home/kumar/Dokumente/trial/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense` ?

Comment: Yes Zulan, this file(Dense.c) exists in that path.

Comment: It should be `Dense` without an extension.

Comment: If there is a `.c` file in your `include` directory, something is really wrong with your installation...

Comment: I have installed Eigen in a classic way : the file `Dense` exists : it is located in `/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen`.

Comment: I have installed Eigen again. The file Dense exists without any extension. It is located in the same location as before and I tried to compile the code again. The same error still occurs again